# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS: Display Port no signal after bootloader

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, displayport

My System failed to display anything after waking from sleep. Rebooting showed the usual GRUB bootloader but then the display shows no signal.

My System:

- Intel i5 4590 using integrated graphics.
- Gigabyte H81TN
- Kernel 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu

Launching with failsafe x provides Display Port but problem persists on any regular boot.

I can get output from HDMI just not from display port when booting normally.

I have tried `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` & `apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel` to no avail.

`/var/log/kern.log | grep ERROR` shows

```
Sep 25 23:06:30 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [13927.364875] [drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pipe A
Sep 25 23:06:30 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [13927.364891] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
Sep 30 21:59:19 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [212918.484179] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 22:06:17 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [213336.524786] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 22:07:41 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [213420.772726] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 22:43:41 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [215580.888734] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 23:31:07 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216136.075171] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 23:38:51 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216599.784885] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 23:43:41 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216889.335360] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 23:43:55 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216903.775710] [drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pipe A
Sep 30 23:43:55 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216903.775724] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
Sep 30 23:43:55 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216903.812338] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
Sep 30 23:45:04 prp-tn-nix-mk-iv kernel: [216960.153895] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
```

I've been having problems with the suspend more before but this is the first time rebooting has failed me :c
Any Ideas?

Comment: check you display settings, sounds link the HDMI is set as primary display or the display port is turned off

Comment: DP is set to primary, even when I plug both in. Is there a way I can check to see if display port is turned off? It only happens when the kernel loads as grub and my BIOS show up fine on DisplayPort.